# How to control 4 8x8 led matrices that are chained together and are powered with the Max7219?

Tags: raspberry-pi, microcontroller, spi

I want to control each individual pixel of the matrices using the Raspberrypi, but I just do not know how and what data I have to send.

I already looked into the SPI interface, but after reading this [article](https://projects-raspberry.com/driving-the-max7219-with-the-raspberry-pi/) in which he did not get it working using it and did it manually because of it, I am unsure what to do.

It is also very hard to debug because I just cannot check when and what data is being sent

I also check various python libraries, but I could not get them running, even after installing every dependency
But it's unnecessary, as I do not want to use python.

I never did anything like this so I am very inexperienced.

I wired it up like in this [guide](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2018/11/22/displaying-max7219-dot-matrix-using-raspberry-pi/) and  wrote some code in rust to send data over the SPI interface:

```rs
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use spidev::{Spidev, SpidevOptions, SpiModeFlags};

fn create_spi() -> io::Result<Spidev> {
    let mut spi = Spidev::open("/dev/spidev0.0")?;
    let options = SpidevOptions::new()
         .bits_per_word(8)
         .max_speed_hz(20_000)
         .mode(SpiModeFlags::SPI_MODE_0)
         .build();
    spi.configure(&options)?;
    Ok(spi)
}

fn main() {
    let mut spi = create_spi().unwrap();
    spi.write(&[0x01, 0x02, 0x03]).unwrap();
}
```

After running it on the Pi it seems like it sent the data successfully without panic, but I cannot check if it really worked.

On the matrix nothing was displayed as expected.

Could someone explain to me how to configure the SPI connection and what data I have to send to initialize the matrix and then display something on it?

### Update

after I took a look at [this driver](https://github.com/almindor/max7219/blob/master/src/lib.rs) I am now able to display values from 0 to 255 on the first and fourth matrix in the first line.
here is the code:

```rs
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use spidev::{Spidev, SpidevOptions, SpiModeFlags};

use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;


// Possible command register values on the display chip.
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Command {
    Noop = 0x00,
    Digit0 = 0x01,
    Digit1 = 0x02,
    Digit2 = 0x03,
    Digit3 = 0x04,
    Digit4 = 0x05,
    Digit5 = 0x06,
    Digit6 = 0x07,
    Digit7 = 0x08,
    DecodeMode = 0x09,
    Intensity = 0x0A,
    ScanLimit = 0x0B,
    Power = 0x0C,
    DisplayTest = 0x0F,
}

// Decode modes for BCD encoded input.
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub enum DecodeMode {
    NoDecode = 0x00,
    CodeBDigit0 = 0x01,
    CodeBDigits3_0 = 0x0F,
    CodeBDigits7_0 = 0xFF,
}

fn create_spi() -> io::Result<Spidev> {
    let mut spi = Spidev::open("/dev/spidev0.0")?;
    let options = SpidevOptions::new()
         .bits_per_word(8)
         .max_speed_hz(20_000)
         .mode(SpiModeFlags::SPI_MODE_0)
         .build();
    spi.configure(&options)?;
    Ok(spi)
}

fn main() {
    let mut spi = create_spi().unwrap();

    // turns on 4 displays (address, command, on)
    for display in 0..4_u8 {
        spi.write(&[display, 0x0c, 0x01]).unwrap();
    }

    // sets decode mode (adress, mode) to 0x00
    spi.write(&[0x00, 0x09, 0x00]).unwrap();

    // writes data (address, digit, data)
    for data in 0..255 {
        spi.write(&[0x00, 0x01, data]).unwrap();
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to access the other lines or individual matrices.

### Update 2

I now cleaned up the code and found out that setting the scan limit to 7 lets you draw data to all 8 lines
here is the code:

```rs
#![allow(dead_code)]

use spidev::Spidev;
use std::io::prelude::*;

// Maximum number of addrs connected in series supported
const MAX_DISPLAYS: usize = 8;

// Digits per addr
const MAX_DIGITS: usize = 8;

// Possible command register values on the addr chip.
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Command {
    Noop = 0x00,
    Digit0 = 0x01,
    Digit1 = 0x02,
    Digit2 = 0x03,
    Digit3 = 0x04,
    Digit4 = 0x05,
    Digit5 = 0x06,
    Digit6 = 0x07,
    Digit7 = 0x08,
    DecodeMode = 0x09,
    Intensity = 0x0A,
    ScanLimit = 0x0B,
    Power = 0x0C,
    DisplayTest = 0x0F,
}

// Decode modes for BCD encoded input.
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub enum DecodeMode {
    NoDecode = 0x00,
    CodeBDigit0 = 0x01,
    CodeBDigits3_0 = 0x0F,
    CodeBDigits7_0 = 0xFF,
}

pub struct Matrix {
    pub spi: Spidev,
    pub devices: u8,
    pub decode_mode: DecodeMode
}
impl Matrix {
    pub fn power_on(&mut self) {
        for addr in 0..self.devices {
            self.spi.write(&[addr, Command::Power as u8, 0x01]).unwrap();
        }
    }
    pub fn power_off(&mut self) {
        for addr in 0..self.devices {
            self.spi.write(&[addr, Command::Power as u8, 0x00]).unwrap();
        }
    }
    pub fn set_decode_mode(&mut self, addr: u8, mode: DecodeMode) {
        // sets decode mode (adress, command, mode)
        self.spi.write(&[addr, Command::DecodeMode as u8, mode as u8]).unwrap();
    }
    pub fn send_command(&mut self, addr: u8, command: Command, value: u8) {
        self.spi.write(&[addr, command as u8, value]).unwrap();
    }
    pub fn draw_raw(&mut self, addr: u8, data: &[u8; MAX_DIGITS]) {
        let mut digit: u8 = 1;
        for b in data {
            // addr ..
            self.spi.write(&[addr, digit, *b]).unwrap();
            digit += 1;
        }
    }
    pub fn clear_addr(&mut self, addr: u8) {
        for i in 1..9 {
            self.spi.write(&[addr, i, 0x00]).unwrap();
        }
    }
    pub fn set_intensity(&mut self, addr: u8, intesity: u8) {
        self.spi.write(&[addr, Command::Intensity as u8, intesity]).unwrap();
    }
}
```

```rs
let spi = create_spi().unwrap();
let mut matrix = Matrix{
    spi,
    devices: 4, // 4 displays chained together, not working rn
    decode_mode: DecodeMode::NoDecode
};
matrix.power_on();
matrix.send_command(0x00, Command::ScanLimit, 0x07);
matrix.draw_raw(0x00, &[
    0b1001001,
    0b0110110,
    0b1001001,
    0b0110110,
    0b1001001,
    0b0110110,
    0b1001001,
    0b0110110
]);

sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
matrix.power_off();
```

But It is displayed on the first and fourth display and I am still not able to control them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I partially solved my problem I will mark it as solved.

I opened a [updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70497554/i-am-only-able-to-control-the-first-out-of-four-8x8-led-matrices-powered-by-max7?noredirect=1#comment124630993_70497554) on how to control multiple matrices chained together.